# Issue while creating a table in Hive

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive

When i try to create a table using following command

**

> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stocks ( exchange STRING, symbol
>   STRING, ymd STRING, price_open FLOAT, price_high FLOAT, price_low
>   FLOAT, price_close FLOAT, volume INT, price_adj_close FLOAT) ROW
>   FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION '/data/stocks';

**

Error shown :

> NoViableAltException(96@[])   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.identifier(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:11627)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.identifier(HiveParser.java:40133)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.columnNameType(HiveParser.java:34747)
>     ...     ..  ..  ..  ..  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212) FAILED:
>   ParseException line 2:0 cannot recognize input near 'exchange'
>   'string' ',' in column specification

But when i surround column names with backticks .. it works ..

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stocks(
`exchange` STRING,
`symbol` STRING,
`ymd` STRING,
`price_open` FLOAT,
`price_high` FLOAT,
`price_low` FLOAT,
`price_close` FLOAT,
`volume` INT,
`price_adj_close` FLOAT)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LOCATION '/in/stocks/';
```

Can someone please explain whats the logic behind this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hive 0.12 and earlier, only alphanumeric and underscore characters are allowed in table and column names.

In Hive 0.13 and later, column names can contain any Unicode character (see HIVE-6013). Any column name that is specified within backticks (`) is treated literally.

You may refer : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6013

Hope this helps!